# Conference call: how to represent oneself?

Tags: grammar

Every time when I am on the call we do quick round to state names. When it is my turn I just want to say that I am the only person representing one end and  this part creates some confusion. It is not fully clear for me what the correct form is.  Should I say:

> From my end, we have only myself.

What are other potential phrases that I can use in this particular situation?

Comment: The problem is with the word 'end'. 'End' is not well defined. If you said "I am the only person from this department' or 'I am the only person from at this location' it would be completely clear. Of course if your colleagues do understand what 'end' means, then what you say is also clear.

Comment: Agree with @DJClayworth- Ninja, please tell us what you mean by "one end".  Do  you mean you are alone on the phone (and not in a conference room with other people) do you mean that you are the only person representing a particular viewpoint in a round-table discussion. Do you mean that your are the only representative for one side of a two-way negotiation??

Comment: Many thanks :). Actually my question was related to the second part of statement.  Would it be ok if i just say "from my side we have only myself?

Comment: Maybe : At this end, I'll be the only participant.

Comment: Maybe this should be migrated to the http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Just say your name and your role/department/location. If other people have the identical dept/location, that will be clear from when they say it. If no one says the same as you, then also it will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

From a clarity standpoint, I would suggest something like this:

> "This is Ninja, and I'll be representing my team on this call."

This way, everyone knows who you are and that you're the one speaking on behalf of your team.

From a grammatical standpoint, what you asked in your question sounds acceptable, but it would come across as awkward to me if I were another person on the call.

I hope this is helpful!